# Avoid sharing objects between contexts using nginx and ember.js

Tags: nginx, proxy, node-js

I have 2 differents applications in ember.js: "host1:3000/appA" and "host2:3001/appB". I use nginx so that the client can access appA and appB through a single domain, that is: "mydomain.com/appA" and "mydomain.com/appB". Everything is correct but the applications are sharing "store" ember object. So if I login into appA, I also login into appB. How can I prevent session sharing between applications?.

I use this config, but doesnt wotk"

```
location /appA {
  proxy_pass http://host1:3000;
  proxy_cookie_path /appA /appA;
}

location /appB {
  proxy_pass http://host2:3001;
  proxy_cookie_path /appB /appB;
}
```